# Why should I use capybara, as it is possible to use selenium itself directly?

Tags: testing, selenium, integration-testing, capybara, capybara-webkit

From what I have read, selenium itself has the commands(and gem) to actually mimic web page interactions, so what is the necessity to use capybara?

Answer (score 3):

Using capybara over selenium-webdriver provides the following benefits:

- It's a higher level API, which means you can use the same API for non-Javascript pages or static HTML, or swap in a different driver, such as capybara-webkit
- It's designed specifically for testing a web application through the UI, so it has useful methods for asserting that the page is correct
- It automatically handles many of the sticky synchronization issues you can run into when testing with a real browser
- It's designed for testing rack applications, so it will boot and manage background servers for you